# Regex parameter url if exists

Tags: regex

I have got this string:

```
tcp://10.0.0.1:11211?rep=12&timeout=12
```

so I tried with:

```
(tcp://.+):([0-9]+)\?.*\&+timeout=([0-9]+).*
```

I need to retrieve:

- `tcp://10.0.0.1` that is the server
- `11211` that is the port
- `timeout` parameter value (in this case 12)

The `tcp://10.0.0.1:11211` part exists in any case and so I need it, but the query part is not mandatory, so my problem is that if `?` or `timeout` or `=` don't exist the regex doesn't retrun anything.
Due to my inexperience I'm not able to solve this problem,how can I achive this result?

[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/uN1mX7/1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make the pattern after the match optional by adding `?`:

```
(tcp://.+):([0-9]+)(\?.*\&?timeout=([0-9]+).*)?
                   ↑      ↑                  ↑↑
```

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/uN1mX7/3)

Comment: Doesn't capture: `tcp://10.0.0.1:11211?timeout=12`

Comment: it tooks 100 steps to do it

Answer (score 4):

How about creating a new capture group after the port

```
([a-zA-Z]{3,4}://.+?):(\d+)(.+?timeout=(\d+).?)?
```

It finishes up the;

`tcp://10.0.0.1:11211` in 28 steps

`tcp://10.0.0.1:11211?timeout=12` in 42 steps

`tcp://10.0.0.1:11211?rep=12&timeout=12` in 48 steps

Comment: Doesn't capture: `tcp://10.0.0.1:11211?timeout=12`

Answer (score 0):

The following regex seems to work for me.

```
(tcp://.+):([0-9]+)(\?.*\&+timeout=([0-9]+).*|)
```

It’s based on your regex. The part after the interrogation mark (`\?.*\&+timeout=([0-9]+).*`) has just been enclosed in a `(...|)`.

It is usual to use `(pattern|)` if something might not exist, but you need the regex to match the whole string nonetheless.

Comment: Doesn't capture: `tcp://10.0.0.1:11211?timeout=12`